# How to how can I parse several text files and get required output appended to a single file. (for Documentation)

Tags: python, documentation, bdd, python-behave

I am using Python - Behave framework, for executing BDD tests where I have the tests written in 'Feature & scenarios', and related python code in 'Steps'

Q.  What are possible approaches to capture the written tests for documentation purpose, for these BDD tests. ie. capturing content from 'feature' and its corresponding 'Scenarios' which describe the tests performed.

I have tried using :
- ' Pydoc' for capturing Names of the python files used, Functions and associated comments.

```
python -m pydoc <Tests>
```

But I want to get the documentation from the tests written in *.features files.

**Here is an example of a Feature file with couple of test scenarios.**

```
# Tests\Process_Order.feature
Feature: Verifying the processed files
# Tests to verify the Order processed details

  Scenario: Did we have ALL the required files
     Given a set of specific files that we must have
        | Files |
        | One.txt |
        | Two.txt |
        | Three.txt |

      When we check that files received match our specific required files
      Then we have the correct files to be processed

   Scenario: Are all required files filled with Order ids
      Given a set of specific files that we must have order ids
        | Files |
        | Order_Aug.csv |
        | Order_Sep.csv |
        | Order_Oct.csv |

      When we check that all files have order ids
      Then we have correctly processed order files
```

**Expected Output for documentation:**

```
File: Process_Order.Feature

Feature: Verifying the processed files
# Tests to verify the Order processed details

Scenario: Did we have ALL the required files
Scenario: Are all required files filled with Order ids
```

**Updated**

I am trying parsing the text files, by Python but need to parse several text feature files and get all the required content from those multiple files, appended to a single document file.
                                                                                                          `with open('C\Tests\Process_Order.feature', 'r') as in_file, open('bdd_outfile.txt', 'a') as out_file:
    for line in in_file:
        if 'Feature' in line:
            out_file.write(line)
        if 'Scenario' in line:
            out_file.write(line)` 
Please suggest if this right way and how can I parse several feature files and get all the expected outcome from those multiple files, appended to a single document file.

Comment: Can you add an example feature and an example of your expected output? It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Hi Greg, edited and updated with an example feature and expected output for documentation.

Comment: For one thing, I wouldn't put the name of the feature file as a comment in the feature file. What happens when you rename the file? The comment doesn't get updated, I bet. Furthermore, you have a comment about what the feature is concerned with. This should be captured in the description of the feature. You are missing the "In order to verify an order has been processed / As a `<kind of user>` / I want to `<perform some kind of action>`" part at the top, beneath the feature title.

Comment: Edited my request, can you suggest how can I parse several feature files and get all the expected outcome from those multiple files, appended to a single document file. plz ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For documentation of your feature files, use *ReStructured Text* (`*.rst`) files and Sphinx as documentation generation

For documentation of your step implementations:

- RAW mode: Include your Python step implementations in `*.rst` and generate docs with Sphinx
- Generate Sphinx based documentation of your step implementation by using the "sphinx.steps" formatter in behave, like: `behave -f sphinx.steps --dry-run features/`

SEE ALSO:

- http://www.sphinx-doc.org/
- [Example: Sphinx generated page that includes a *.feature file](http://behave.github.io/behave.example/tutorials/tutorial01.html)
- [Example: ReStructuredText for generated page above](http://behave.github.io/behave.example/_sources/tutorials/tutorial01.rst.txt)